# IEDriver always thows nosuchelementexception

Tags: java, exception, webdriver, internet-explorer-11

Browser: IE11
IEDriver: IEDriverServer_x64_3.3.0
The code Snippet:

```
public class DownloadinIE 
{
    long timeout = 1000;
    public String classname = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()).toString();
    String downloadPath = \\ur download path;
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup()
    {
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }
    @Test
    public void download() throws InterruptedException
    {
        driver.get("https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[title='64 bit Download']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".fa.fa-download")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        BaseLibrary.verifyFileDownloaded(downloadPath);
    }
}
```

Error Msg:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == .fa.fa-download (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 961 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: 'A', ip: '192.168.0.102', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_74'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:17524/, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: f75c788e-f130-4531-9f0a-a4bc714d9e76
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=.fa.fa-download}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:492)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:430)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at reports.WaitAndDownloadIE.download(WaitAndDownloadIE.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:669)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:877)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1201)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:776)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:634)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:425)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:420)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:385)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1318)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1243)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1161)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1129)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

verifyFileDownloaded method verifies if the file is downloaded completely. My problem is driver is not recognizing any object right from the first element click. This test runs well in Firefox and Chrome. What is the problem here? Please provide your suggestions.

My application needs to be tested in IE for a similar function. Thats why I am trying this way

Comment: Webdriver with Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that your InternetExplorer => internet options => Security all are disabled or a level is low. This helped me.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your suggestion is mandatory for running in IE and I accept it. But in my case it didnt help and I tried an alternative approach and it worked fine